# How to display ( and work with ) related data without using a table component?

Tags: tables, data-tables, relations

I'm working with an external system where users can create entities and link them bidirectionally. One entity is the source / the parent and the other entity is the target / the child. So one link will be Parent -> is parent of -> Child and the other link direction is Child -> is child of -> Parent.

Most users using such systems are working with tools like Excel and setup their workflows using tables because auditors must review all the data later on.

Inside a sheet you begin with a "leading element", other columns are related to this "leading column" based on their relations. Given the following example:

- Leading type: Manufacturer
- Following type ( parent ): Store ( selling products from different manufacturers )
- Following type ( child ): Product ( from manufacturer )
- Following type ( child of store ) : Employee

with the data

- Manufacturer 1 is selling products in Store 1, 2 ( with Employees 1, 2 ) and owns products 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
- Manufacturer 2 is selling products in Store 2 ( with Employees 7, 8 ) and owns products 1, 4

Based on the requirements users create their Excel sheets to fit their needs. I created a table component that would generate a table similiar to this one

[image]

- The column order may vary
- I'm working with rowspans to span "parent" elements across their children
- It is not necessary that the app runs on mobile devices ( no responsive design / desktop browser app only )
- There is quite more things to do. Entities have fields, some are displayed in the cell.

Now the tricky part: I don't like that table approach, it's hard to calculate and quite messy. Imagine that each manufacturer is selling n products in m stores with k employees ( and there might be 30 more columns ) that table would be gigantic. And no one on earth would read 30.000 lines of data.

I know, pagination, sorts and filters help but I'm thinking about a different visualization. The tool Gource inspired me

[image]

but the problem is that so many relationships would produce "too many" lines on screen. And you wouldn't be able to display the entity fields ( maybe on hover, but you can't display entities with fields in a good way ).

And most users are working column wise, they write down each manufacturer first, then each store, ...

I thought about using something like stepper components ( https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers/#usage ) but they are not able to deal with multiple outgoing branches ( relationships ) and users are loosing the big picture ( the rest of the data flying around )

Do you have any ideas how to visualize such relationships for users focusing on tables and tools like Excel?

Comment: Who are the users? And how do they interact with the information?

Comment: "Manufacturer 1...owns products 1...4... Manufacturer 2...owns products 1, 4" That seems to contradict. Can you clarify what "owns" and "products" mean? And what is a product the child of? Store? Or Manufacturer?

Comment: Are you looking for a [Tree Grid](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/treegrid/treegrid-1.html#ex_label), maybe?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles If a _product_ isn't a single article but a type (e.g rubber boots, wherever they come from) it can be owned by/come from different manufacturers.

Comment: @Andy The Tree Grid looks great. I didn't know that, too. Thx for the hint. However, apparently it's just for hierarchically nested 1:n relationships: "_A treegrid widget presents a hierarchical data grid [...]. Any row in the hierarchy may have child rows, [...]_". The relationships the OP describes are much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

According to the infos in the question and if there aren't any missing there exist the following [relationships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model):

- Store – m:n – Manufacturer, derived from:

  - "*Store ( selling products from different manufacturers )*" → 1:n
  - "*Manufacturer [...] is selling products in Store[s] 1, 2*" → 1:n

    two 1:n relationships in the opposite direction → m:n.
- Manufacturer – m:n – Product, derived from:

  - "*Manufacturer [1, 2] is selling products*"
- Store – m:n or 1:n – Employee

  This is not completely clear because under "*with the data*" there's:

  - in Store 1, 2 ( with Employees 1, 2 ) → m:n

  while in the table:

  - rows 3 and 4: Store 1 has assigned Emp 1 and 2 → 1:n
  - rows 5, 6, 8, 9: Store 2 has assigned Emp 7 and 8 → 1:n

Basically a single table (like in XL) isn't the proper tool to hold and show such information clearly and precise because according to the snippet in the question:

- In Store 2:

  - rows 5 and 8: Emp 7 sells products 1 and 3 only and
  - rows 6 and 9: Emp 8 sells product 4 only

I don't think that reflects real life **AND there's also a contradiction** for the second point:

- According to cell A6 Emp 8 sells in Store 2.
- According to cell A9 Emp 8 ***does not*** sell in Store 2, since the cell is not merged with A8. (But that could be "just" a formatting mistake.)

I agree with "*that table approach, it's hard to calculate and quite messy*" if I'm allowed to replace "*quite*" with *totally*.

So, first things first:

- Design an [Entity–relationship model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) on paper (or in an according app).
- Select a tool that's made to handle entities and their relationships by design: A relational database.
- Represent your entities (Store, Manufacturer, Product, Employee) with tables.
- Establish proper relationships between the tables.

  Generally: In case of m:n represent their relationships with intersect tables.

  | In your special case: |
  | --- |
  | Since there's just one attribute for each entity: a number, you'd just need (depending on "*Store – m:n or 1:n – Employee*" above): |
  | - three intersect tables (StoreManufacturer, StoreEmployee, ManufacturerProduct) or |
  | - two tables (Store, Employee) and two intersect tables (StoreManufacturer, ManufacturerProduct). |
- See how you can get the info your users need out of the tables (with their relationships) with an appropriate query.
- Then (and only then) think of how to display this info to your users.